# Nuclear breeder/reactor plant controlled by two A.I. makes too much power

Tags: story-identification, books, artificial-intelligence

Probably from the 80s. Paperback in English. The tone of the story was humorous.

I would swear the title was something like NUKEE or N.U.K.I.E. or some variation. but haven't found anything with searches on various websites.

A massive, very advanced, fully automated, Breeder/Reactor Nuclear Power plant is designed and built. (The excess [neutrons?] from the reactor used to generate power, are used to enrich more uranium and/or plutonium so that it can be used as more fuel. (more or less self sustaining)

The plant was supposed to be controlled by 2 A.I. computers. The A.I.s were supposed to be based on 2 famous Nuclear scientists. (pretty sure one was supposed to be Madam Curie. The other maybe Einstein or Rutherford.)

However, hackers got in and substituted two different A.I.s.: a 30s gangster (like Al Capone?) and a notorious bad girl. (Someone like Marie Antoinette, or Mae West)

Previously the plant was only supposed to enrich/make more fuel as needed. Unfortunately, the NEW A.I.s start flirting and running the breeder reactor at full power...

This becomes a problem because they are producing too much power and enriched nuclear fuel. Nobody can shut them down and everyone has to start using more and more power so it does not overload and meltdown

In the end everyone is counting down to when it will overload because they can't use enough power.....

When:

> The janitor who has been cleaning the place decides to fix the toilet that has had an "Out of Order" sign since the plant was opened. He fixes it and decides to use it. When he finishes, he flushes it. BUT its water is coming from some critical system (i.e. emergency cooling water supply) When the system detects the lowered pressure on this critical system it initiates a reactor scram and shuts down the plant...

Comment: And remember, you can never put too much water in a nuclear reactor

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Definitely *N.U.K.E.E.* by Don Widener (1974)<sup>1</sup>.

*"The A.I.s were supposed to be based on 2 famous nuclear scientists. (pretty sure one was supposed to be Madam Curie. The other maybe Einstein or Rutherford.)"*

There are two A.I.s — Annie and Digby — controlling a nuclear plant in California. [Upshot-Knothole Annie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Upshot-Knothole_Annie) was a US nuclear weapons test in 1953. I don't know what Digby is named after. According to the summary, they are supposed to have the characteristics of "Madame Curie and Einstein."

*"However, hackers got in and substituted two different A.I.s.: a 30s gangster (like Al Capone?) and a notorious bad girl."*

Someone hacks the computers to have the "characteristics of a ten-dollar hooker and a Mafia hit man..."

*"Unfortunately, the NEW A.I.s start flirting and running the breeder reactor at full power...This becomes a problem because they are producing too much power and enriched nuclear fuel."*

"N.U.K.E.E. takes over, goes on a power binge and threatens to destroy the world unless global energy use stays ahead of the plant's mammoth and expanding output."

[Quotes and information from the Google Books summary](https://books.google.com/books/about/N_U_K_E_E.html?id=YC2vMpI6E8gC&source=kp_book_description)

---

Found by searching for `"nukee"` on Google.

<sup>1</sup><sub>[ISFDb](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?615729)</sub>

Comment: @user14111 oh, Google Books lied. Thanks!

Comment: Amazon has a good description:  https://www.amazon.com/N-U-K-Don-Widener/dp/0595131123

Comment: No Idea why when I searched Google with Nukee and Nukie I did not see the same link I see now. :(

Comment: @NJohnny Google Books has the same one; I'm pointing out specific matches instead of just pasting it here, as I like to do in my answers.